# Converting a hexadecimal number to binary in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to convert a hex value to a binary value (each bit in the hex string should have an equivalent four bit binary value). I was advised to use this:

```
num = "0ff" # (say for eg.)
bin = "%0#{num.size*4}b" % num.hex.to_i
```

This gives me the correct output `000011111111`. I am confused with how this works, especially `%0#{num.size*4}b`. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can also do:

```
num = "0ff"
num.hex.to_s(2).rjust(num.size*4, '0')
```

You may have already figured out, but, `num.size*4` is the number of digits that you want to pad the output up to with `0` because one hexadecimal digit is represented by four (log_2 16 = 4) binary digits.

Comment: Or, more generally, `num.to_i(16).to_s(2)`

Answer (score 4):

You'll find the answer in the documentation of `Kernel#sprintf` (as pointed out by the docs for `String#%`):

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001433

Answer (score 4):

This is the most straightforward solution I found to convert from hexadecimal to binary:

```rb
['DEADBEEF'].pack('H*').unpack('B*').first # => "11011110101011011011111011101111"
```

And from binary to hexadecimal:

```rb
['11011110101011011011111011101111'].pack('B*').unpack1('H*') # => "deadbeef"
```

Here you can find more information:

- `Array#pack`: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-pack
- `String#unpack1` (similar to `unpack`): https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-unpack1

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your original question, but I would assume that a lot of people coming here are, instead of looking to turn hexadecimal to actual "0s and 1s" binary output, to *decode* hexadecimal to a **byte string representation** (in the spirit of such utilities as `hex2bin`). As such, here is a good method for doing exactly that:

```rb
def hex_to_bin(hex)
  # Prepend a '0' for padding if you don't have an even number of chars
  hex = '0' << hex unless (hex.length % 2) == 0
  hex.scan(/[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}/).inject('') { |encoded, byte| encoded << [byte].pack('H2') }
end
```

Getting back to hex again is much easier:

```rb
def bin_to_hex(bin)
  bin.unpack('H*').first
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting the string of hex digits back to binary is just as easy. Take the hex digits two at a time (since each byte can range from 00 to FF), convert the digits to a character, and join them back together.

`def hex_to_bin(s) s.scan(/../).map { |x| x.hex.chr }.join end`